# putting a debugging console window in your app

Tags: wpf, console, debugging

I'm starting to develop a simple application in VS9 and I decided to use WPF and the MVVM paradigm for it.

Still being a bit unexperienced with VS deveopment in general and WPF-controls in peculiar, I would like to ask how I should proceed to establish a little debug console window that takes perhaps 1/4 of the main window and sits kind of docked in the bottom of the window.

I would use it for writing trace or debug messages into it while my application runs or while I'm debugging it in the development phase.

Anyway, what type of control should I use and how do I write to it?

Alternatively I was thinking of using a Console window separately from my WPF application but 
that wouldn't be so desirable, actually.

--
Chris

Comment: See that related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389264/trace-listener-to-write-to-a-text-box-wpf-application

Answer (score 2):

Rather than write logging messages to a window:

- You would be better off writing messages using a proper logging framework (such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html))
- Alternatively you could use [Trace](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788) statements if you want to avoid using complex logging frameworks for a simple application.

If you do want to write messages to a window or console in your application, then the recommendation would be to **use a separate window** - that way the presence of the console / debug window doesn't affect the layout of your main window.

As for getting a debug console to "stick" to the bottom of your window, take a look at some articles (or perhaps a book) on layout in wpf, and get used to how the layout system works in wpf.

> http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=c76411d6-5350-4a10-b6bb-f1481c167ecf
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF1.aspx
>   http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/WPF-Control-Layout/

You should probably be able to get the desired effect using a [Dock Panel](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DockPanel.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a debugging window, use this opportunity to get yourself familiar with [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html), and write to a file. log4net is brilliant (generally) and a very widely-used logging system.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic method is to use `System.Diagnostics.Trace` for writing out debug messages. You can attach to these messages with a `TraceListener` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389264/trace-listener-to-write-to-a-text-box-wpf-application), or you can use a separate tool such as **[DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx)** to display these messages. Please note that while debugging, trace messages will also be displayed in Visual Studio's *Output* window.