# Converting a Console Application into a GUI that uses a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, console, backgroundworker, console-application, trace

I am converting a console application into a Windows Forms Application and a DLL. The Windows Forms Application uses a BackgroundWorker to have the DLL perform a computationally heavy task.

Left over from the console application, the DLL is still littered with `Console.WriteLine()` statements. I would like to direct what used to be printed to the console into a `TextBox` in the Windows Form. Ideally, I would like to hook a stream from the DLL up to the text box during form initialization and be done with it. I am concerned that this might not be thread safe with the BackgroundWorker.

The best approach I have found is to change `Console.WriteLine()` to `Trace.WriteLine()` in the DLL and then follow the approach at [Trace listener to write to a text box (WPF application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389264/trace-listener-to-write-to-a-text-box-wpf-application) but I still have concerns with the BackgroundWorker and am not too keen on appending text to an existing string (there is a lot of text and IMO strings aren't meant/optimized to have lots of text concatenated on them).

What is the best way to print the old console output to the text box that will be safe with a BackgroundWorker?

Comment: Does it have to print as its generated or can it print all at once at the end ?   And the question more concerned with the mechanics of cross thread calls, or with capturing the `Console.WriteLine` output without changing the code ?

Comment: I would like it to print as the out put is generated or (more reasonably) when the 'ReportProgress' event is raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following blog post may be what you're looking for:

http://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/

I think it describes exactly what you're asking for. Basically it uses `Console.SetOut` to redirect the console output to a stream writer of your own. Read the comments below the post for some additional information on handling thread issues.