# Copy complete console output in a WPF TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, console, tracelistener

I' ve several places in my C# code, that output things to the Console. Some using Console.Writeline, some via TraceListeners like System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener.

Now I want to display all that output in a WPF textbox.
Is it possible to bind the console output 1:1 in some way to a TextBox?

Or do I have to change every single call of TraceListeners or Console.Writeline to add the output to textbox.text additionally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to intercept Console output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024172/is-it-possible-to-intercept-console-output)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Console.OpenStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16f09842.aspx) to intercept `Console.Writeline()`- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6024185/7292772) and this [link](http://nmarkou.blogspot.com/2011/12/redirect-console-output-to-textbox.html) explain how to implement a `TextBoxStreamWriter` and inject it in standard output stream.

As for `ConsoleTraceListener` - you should be able to write your own textbox based `TraceListener` and assign it to appropriate `TraceSources` (as they support multiple trace listeners). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389289/7292772) highlights how to implement the same.

More details regarding trace sources and listeners can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2006/09/14/trace-sources-in-wpf/).